# How to Use Pager Tab Strip on Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, tabnavigator

I want to implement tab view to my xamarin forms application. But xamarine tabs gives two diferent tab views for android and IOS. I want to Use the android tab view on both my android and ios applications as shown in the below picture. Is this possible. [image]